# Создание пользователя в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Итак, уважаемые. Читаю книгу PHP5 для начинающих. Некоторые вещи пропустил(считаю пока не нужным xml и работу с каталогами), но, подойдя к главе mysql, обнаружил вывод ошибки при написании следующего запроса в mysql monitor.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO user VALUES(
-> 'localhost',
–> 'phpuser',
–> Password('phppass'),
–> 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N',
–> 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N',
–> 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N',
–> 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N',
–> 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N');
```

Ошибка такого рода.

> `Data truncated for column 'ssl_mysql' at row 1`

Что это за ssl_mysql такое, если в таблице его нет? И почему row 1? Объясните незнающему.

ЗЫ: я пытаюсь создать нового пользователя mysql(база mysql, таблица user).

Comment: кое-что изменил, теперь ошибка:
Data truncated for column 'ssl_type' at row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какие-то урюки эту книгу написали. Так пользователей не создавали уже в версии 3.23.

Не надо напрямую писать в таблицу `mysql.user` без нужды. Создавайте пользователя как положено, командой `GRANT`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'
```

Подробности [в документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html).

Answer (score 1):

Для полноты картины пользователя можно создать и простой командой CREATE:
    CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'